# Select Base table id based on Left joining sub queries id values

Tags: sql, postgresql

consider i should select my a.id which is in d.id

```
 SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.value_entered_date,
  d.name,
  d.order_date
  d.zip
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN
 (
SELECT 
b.id,b.name,c.value,b.order_date
FROM table b
LEFT join table c
on b.id=c.id
) as d
WHERE a.id in (d.id)
and a.value = d.value
```

Here i should select my a.id which is in d.id

Comment: What's the question

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It is not clear from your post what you are asking and trying to achieve. Please be clear, add more text, sample data and expected output.

Comment: @eurotrash  i should a table id based on Left joining sub queries d id values

Answer (score 0):

Use just left join

```
SELECT 
      a.id,
      a.value_entered_date,
      d.name,
      d.order_date
      d.zip
    FROM table a
    where a.id in ( select d.id from 
     (
    SELECT 
    b.id,b.name,c.value,b.order_date
    FROM table b
    LEFT join table c
    on b.id=c.id
    ) as d
 )
```

Comment: i tried this on using left join i get many column in a.id which is not required
i should a table id based on Left joining sub queries d id values

Comment: we don't need to use left join on joining table 'a' and  table 'd' here

Comment: @Nandha no need if you just want to see in result all rows of a which contain d.id

Comment: also out of curiosity if we want to check another column the same way "like a.value_entered_date from d.order_date in addition to a.id from d.id "

Comment: @Nandha in that case you have to join ,btw if my answer helps to you then please accept  answer as a SO appreciation

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating that you just want a `join` condition.  This would look like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.value_entered_date,
       d.name, d.order_date d.zip
FROM table a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.id, b.name, c.value, b.order_date
      FROM table b LEFT join
           table c
           ON b.id = c.id
     ) d
     ON a.id = d.id AND a.value = d.value ;
```

I'm pretty sure this can actually be simplified to:

```
SELECT a.id, a.value_entered_date,
       b.name, b.order_date, c.zip
FROM table a LEFT JOIN
     table b
     ON a.id = b.id LEFT JOIN
     table c
     ON a.id = c.id AND a.value = c.value
```